# How to submit job over dispatcher http api (tcp/8081) on AWS EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-flink, apache-beam, amazon-emr

I am trying to submit job to *apache flink* on AWS EMR over `tcp/8081` .

I was assuming AWS EMR has similar architecture to *cluster manager using dispatcher* as described in [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=65147077) which expose *dispatcher web frontend* to clients. However, looking at [online doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/flink-jobs.html) general way to submit job to flink is to use aws cli sdk not through `tcp/8081`.

I use *apache beam Flink Runner* as client and what I need is *dispatcher web front end*.

Where can I find find *dispatcher frontend* equivalent to `tcp/8081` on AWS EMR ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the `Web Front end` on *Flink Dashboard* .

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/flink-web-interface.html

The problem for me was *ApplicationMaster* was pointing to *internal address* so I had to change to *public dns* to access to dashboard.

```
http://ec2-x-x-x-x.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:20888/proxy/application_1568859410287_0003/#/jobmanager/log
```

[image: flink dashboard]

Using this address, I was able to submit job to apache flink.
You could get the same address with `yarn application --list` too. You have to login to either *master* or *data* node though.

```
yarn application --list
19/09/20 06:37:51 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-15-54.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal/172.31.15.54:8032
Total number of applications (application-types: [] and states: [SUBMITTED, ACCEPTED, RUNNING]):1
                Application-Id      Application-Name        Application-Type          User           Queue                   State             Final-State             Progress                           Tracking-URL
application_1568859410287_0003  Flink session cluster           Apache Flink        hadoop         default                 RUNNING               UNDEFINED                 100%    http://ip-172-31-1-84.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal:38205
```